# How to delete uploaded PSDs in brackets code editor

Tags: adobe-brackets

After uploading a psd in extract for brackets there is no delete option available. How to clean/delete the unwanted PSDs from creative cloud assets tray?

Answer (score 0):

install and open the creative cloud app, then find the tab named Assets,

In Assets Tab you can see a open folder window....in that you can deleted the unwanted files, then the same will reflect in brackets files.